# calculate the percentage of workers getting wages between $22$ and $58.$

Tags: statistics

I want to calculate the percentage of workers getting wages between $22$ and $58.$ I don't know what to use. Please help me.

$$\begin{cases}Wages&&No~of~Workers\\0-10&&20\\10-20&&45\\20-30&&85\\30-40&&160\\40-50&&70\\50-60&&55\\60-70&&35\\70-80&&30\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly you cannot calculate an exact percentage as the problem (I guess) arises from the categories 20-30 and 50-60.

Indeed, you could have all 85 workers in the 20-30 wage having exactly a wage of 21 or even all of them a wage of exactly 25, both giving you different answers to your initial questions.

All you can be certain of is that all 30-40 and 40-50 are included which is $160+70=230$ people.

Now, to find the number of people having a wage between 22 and 30, I propose assuming a uniform distribution, that is the population is equally spaced over the whole range between 20 and 30.

There are 85 people distributed over 20-30, therefore an estimate of the population over 22-30 is $\frac8{10}85 = 68$

Similarly, find the number of people in the range 50-58. I assume you know how to find a percentage from there.